# mirror and reflect left side movie to the right side in Processing sketch

Tags: processing, pgraphics

I have to reflect and mirror the half of the left video with the right one. I tried this code but when I activate the effect the video shows only the first frame and does not play. The video freezes and i hear the sound. How can I play the video with the effect? thanks!

```
import processing.video.*;
boolean flipVideo = false;
Movie movie;

PGraphics flippedBuffer; // PGraphics buffer for the flipped video
PImage leftHalf;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);
  frameRate(30);
  
  movie = new Movie(this, "movie.mov");
 
  movie.loop();
  movie.read();
 

  flippedBuffer = createGraphics(movie.width, movie.height); // Initialize the buffer
}

void draw() {
  if (movie.available() && overlay.available()) {
    movie.read(); 
  }

  movie.loadPixels();
  

  // Create the flipped video and store it in the PGraphics buffer
 if (flipVideo) {
   flippedBuffer.beginDraw();

 leftHalf = get(0, 0, width/2, height);
  flippedBuffer.translate(width, 0);
  flippedBuffer.scale(-1, 1);
  flippedBuffer.image(leftHalf, 0, 0);
  
  flippedBuffer.endDraw();
  } else {
    flippedBuffer.beginDraw();
    flippedBuffer.image(movie, 0, 0); // Use the original video
    flippedBuffer.endDraw();
  }
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}

void addTuioObject(TuioObject tobj) {
...
}

void removeTuioObject(TuioObject tobj) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Are you able to play the movie without the effect?  Get it working first then add the effect.

Comment: I can play the video without effect with: flippedBuffer.image(movie, 0, 0);
I can also reproduce different effects. But this just doesn't work.

Comment: Did the answer provided answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The following source code will play the same movie side by side with the right movie a mirror image of the left.  Movie dimension was 480 x 270; adjust code accordingly if you test some other size.

```
import processing.video.*;

Movie movie;

void setup() {
  size(960, 270);  // width should be twice movie width
  movie = new Movie(this, "xxxx.mp4");  // file in 'data' sketch folder
  movie.loop(); // Use play() to play just once.
}

void movieEvent(Movie movie) {
  movie.read();  // Read new frames from the movie.
}

void draw() {
  image(movie, 0, 0);  // Display side by side
  image(movie, width/2, 0);
  // mirror image
  pushMatrix();   // so nothing else is affected
  scale(-1, 1);
  image(movie, -480, 0);  // movie width = 480
  popMatrix();
}
```